# Installing nginx without package manager in mac El Capitan

Tags: nginx

Is there a way we can install nginx in mac El Capitan without Homebrew or any other package manager.

I would like understand where it is getting installed etc.,

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to install nginx on MacOSX without using brew or any other package manager?

Comment: This helps !http://www.codepool.biz/how-to-configure-and-install-nginx-on-mac-os-x.html